# Is it memory intensive to store react components in an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

```
{
    ui: <Component />,
}
```

What if an object stores hundreds of these components. Would this be memory intensive?

Comment: Well, things like tree shaking wont work, wich leads to bigger bundle size and slower pageload

Answer (score 1):

It would be no more memory intensive than displaying them in the UI. Behind the scenes, React stores the components as objects, so there is no performance cost.

Comment: But compared to not having this object at all, is it memory intensive?

Comment: @BigCatPublicSafetyAct No, it’s perfectly fine. It’s just a normal js object, it takes very little space

Answer (score 1):

The code `<Component />` transpiles to `React.createElement(Component, null);`, which will return an object that looks roughly like this (dev builds may include extra properties to help with debugging):

```
{
  $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
  key: null,
  props: {}
  ref: null,
  type: Component,
  _owner: null,
}
```

Of those, the `props` and the `type` are the only things that could conceivably have a significant memory footprint. But Component is very likely referenced somewhere else anyway, so i doubt it can be garbage collected whether you create this element or not.

In short, i'd say the memory is only a problem if both of the following are true: 1) the props are very large, and 2) the props would be garbage collected if not for this element.